# NullPointerException after initalizing List

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have the following class: https://paste.md-5.net/mozodifaka.java

I keep getting an NPE at line 281. I've been messing around with it for hours but I can't get it to work. You can clearly see that I am initializing it with `landList = new ArrayList<>()`, so how is `landList` still null?

```
public class Kingdom extends OfflineKingdom implements KingdomEventHandler {

  private transient volatile List<KingdomPlayer> onlineMembers;// = new ArrayList<>();
  private transient volatile List<Kingdom> onlineEnemies;// = new ArrayList<>();
  private transient volatile List<Kingdom> onlineAllies;// = new ArrayList<>();
  private transient volatile int kingdomLand;// = 0;
  private transient volatile List<Land> landList;// = new ArrayList<>();
  private transient volatile int uptime;// = 2;
  private transient volatile Kingdom invader;
  private transient volatile Kingdom invading;
  private transient volatile long invasionStart;

  volatile Location nexus_loc;
  volatile Location home_loc;
  volatile int chestsize;// = 9;
  volatile long timestamp;// = 0;
  volatile int maxMember;// = 10;

  ChampionInfo championInfo;// = new ChampionInfo();
  PermissionsInfo permissionsInfo;// = new PermissionsInfo();
  ArmyInfo armyInfo;// = new ArmyInfo();
  AggressorInfo aggressorInfo;// = new AggressorInfo();
  MisupgradeInfo misupgradeInfo;// = new MisupgradeInfo();
  KingdomChest kingdomChest;// = new KingdomChest();
  PowerUp powerUp;// = new PowerUp();
  TurretUpgradeInfo turretUpgrades;// = new TurretUpgradeInfo();

  private boolean init = false;

  {
    onlineMembers = new ArrayList<>();
    onlineEnemies = new ArrayList<>();
    onlineAllies = new ArrayList<>();
    kingdomLand = 0;
    landList = new ArrayList<>();
    uptime = 2;

    chestsize = 9;
    timestamp = 0;
    maxMember = 10;

    championInfo = new ChampionInfo();
    permissionsInfo = new PermissionsInfo();
    armyInfo = new ArmyInfo();
    aggressorInfo = new AggressorInfo();
    misupgradeInfo = new MisupgradeInfo();
    kingdomChest = new KingdomChest();
    powerUp = new PowerUp();
    turretUpgrades = new TurretUpgradeInfo();

    init = true;
  }

  public Kingdom(String kingdomName) {
    super(kingdomName);
  }

  public void init() {
    if (init == (init = true)) return;
    onlineMembers = new ArrayList<>();
    onlineEnemies = new ArrayList<>();
    onlineAllies = new ArrayList<>();
    kingdomLand = 0;
    landList = new ArrayList<>();
    uptime = 2;

    chestsize = 9;
    timestamp = 0;
    maxMember = 10;

    championInfo = new ChampionInfo();
    permissionsInfo = new PermissionsInfo();
    armyInfo = new ArmyInfo();
    aggressorInfo = new AggressorInfo();
    misupgradeInfo = new MisupgradeInfo();
    kingdomChest = new KingdomChest();
    powerUp = new PowerUp();
    turretUpgrades = new TurretUpgradeInfo();
  }

  public int getLand() {
    init();
    int land = 0;
    for (final Land l : LandManager.landList.values()) {
        if (l.getOwner() == null || !l.getOwner().equals(getKingdomName())) continue;
        landList.add(l); // 281
        land++;
    }
    return land;
  }

  public List<Land> getLandList() {
    getLand();
    return landList;
  }

}
```

Comment: (1) Dumping a link to your code is not sufficient; a [mcve] must be included in the *body* of the question itself. (2) The sort of language you used in your original question is not allowed here; this is a family-friendly site, and you are required to maintain professional decorum. I realize you are frustrated, but that's no excuse. Take a breath before hitting the "Submit" button.

Comment: try to create simple example insted of copy past all your application code with compilation error, this is not good practice to throw your code and ask what is wrong in my code  insted of debug .

Comment: @vaquarkhan it's 20 minutes I'm looking at his code, and if the exception is really at line 281, where it does a "landList.add", I can't figure out what's wrong. The List is volatile and initialized at object construction, so should be safe to access from multiple threads, at least without NPE

Comment: If you find working code then easy to find in eclipse debug mode what is wrong in code .

Comment: @vaquarkhan this seems to be some sort of paid plugin.

Comment: Are you **sure** you are looking at the correct version of your code, i.e. line 281 is _really_ what you _think_ it is? Try to add some debug output (using a logging framework or simply `System.out.println(…)`) to your code at relevant points (e.g. print `landList` before and after the call to `init()` and directly before the `landList.add(l)`).

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at the wrong `ArrayList` instance.

```
LandManager.landList
```

That's a *static* `List` from another class, `LandManager`.

The one you're initializing is inside `Kingdom`.

```
landList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: In line 281 I am using landList from `Kingdom`, not from `LandManager`

Comment: @Priv you're right. I'll give it another look

Comment: @Priv could you post the stacktrace?

Comment: https://paste.md-5.net/simimiputu.css

Comment: @Priv that's pretty strange!

Comment: @Priv I really don't know. I'd try without the "volatile" modifier. Let me know

Comment: @Priv is this object ever cloned by any chance?

Comment: Only thing I know is that the constructor is never called. Object is probably initalized with reflection.

Comment: @Priv Maybe, but you still initialize it inside "init".

Comment: Yep, I've been messing around with it for hours and made the shit volatile. I'll be testing and debugging tomorrow. My testing guy says he's using the latest version of the code but will test again tomorrow.

Comment: @Priv I'd also try removing transient, if the object is cloned via serialization, fields won't be serialized and thus will be null. But that would be irrelevant as apparently you initialize the List inside "init". Let me know

Comment: Making the boolean `init` transient fixed it.

Comment: @Priv mmhh well I can't give you an explanation honestly

Comment: Guess it was cloned somehow.

Comment: @Priv but transient would make it null, because it can no more be serialized